# How to change system date and time(embedded Linux) using QML?

Tags: linux, qt, datetime, qml

How to change the system time and date in QML? I thought this might work from an example, though I have this doubt where the object is being sent. It didn't work. Can some one let me know how to that? Following is my code:

```
  var time = new Date()
  time.setHours(hour)
  time.setMinutes(minute)
  time.setSeconds(secs)
```

Comment: Smells awefully like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please **edit your question** to improve it and give the real motivation and context. What kind of application do you have in mind? If you develop some embedded system, tell that and explain what system is it...

Answer (score 0):

You generally cannot change the system time without root permission, and setting the system time is a whole-system operation for sysadmins. See [settimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html)  and [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

<sup>(So it is not a matter of using Qt or something else; any library using `settimeofday` or `adjtimex` needs root permission)</sup>

Read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html).

And you generally should not change the system time, but have some daemon using [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to adjust it continuously.

Your code is just changing the value of some variable holding some time. It is not changing the system time.

The sysadmin could change the time e.g. with [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) used with `-s` which requires root permission and uses `settimeofday` internally. See also [hwclock(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hwclock.8.html).

Notice that GUI applications should generally not be run as root (and Qt or GTK don't want to be run as root).

If you develop some embedded system and you want the user to set the time, you could consider writting some *small* specialized [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executable which uses [settimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html) and have your GUI application run it (e.g. with [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html)). Be very careful when coding a setuid program (so read [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or some good book on Linux system programming), since you could easily get [vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)). Be aware that *setuid* is the basic mechanism (used by `/bin/login`, `/bin/su`, `/usr/bin/sudo` etc...; it is also used in Android systems or any Unix-derived system) to acquire or change permission. It is tricky to use, so do spend time to understand it.

Perhaps your [`init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) or [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) might be configured to ease such a task....

<sup>(you need to describe your entire system much more to get more help)</sup>

Comment: Then how the user can change it? I am working on an IMX6 platform.

Comment: The user should not change it. You should have some daemon using NTP. And the sysadmin could change it (e.g. by running, *as root*, `date -s` ).

Comment: That's a very user specific application which I can not entirely explain it here (sorry about that). But every phone and PC has the option to change the date and time, the same way I have options for the user to change it if he/she wants to change. How to do that in QML/Javascript?

Comment: As I suggest, write your specialized *setuid* program, and run it from your Qt application. And if you cannot explain your application, you should not ask questions about it on SO.

Comment: BTW, it is mostly a whole-system and sysadmin issue. Is your system running `systemd` ? Or what kind of `init` program?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will use them. Yes my system uses systemd.